# Convergence of a subsequence .

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If every subsequence of $x_n$ has a further subsequence which converges , is it true that the sequence is convergent?

**NOTE** : This is not a duplicate of[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-then) . In this problem it is not given that the subsequences converges to the same limit $x$.

Comment: Just take any bounded sequence which does not converge.

Answer (score 4):

Take the sequence $1,2,1,2,\ldots$ for a counterexample. It is not convergent, yet every subsequence either has an infinite number of ones or infinite number of twos and so has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: OK thanks . Trivial . :P

Comment: What subsequences are supposed to be converging to here?

Comment: Oh, just saw your edit. You're right. I was incorrectly thinking of a subsequence as needing to comprise consecutive terms.