# Floor function and convergence of the sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Sequence $\{a(n)\}$ of real numbers is such that $\forall\space\lambda\in(1,2)$ sequence $a(\lfloor{\lambda}^n\rfloor)$ has a finite limit. Does it follow that $\{a(n)\}$ is convergent?

Comment: Define $S_\lambda = \{\lfloor \lambda^m \rfloor \colon m\in\Bbb N\}$. I believe the following lemma is true: there exists a fixed sequence $\{b_m\}$ of positive integers such that for all $\lambda\in(1,2)$, the intersection of sets $\{b_m\colon m\in\Bbb N\} \cap S_\lambda$ is finite. If true, the lemma would imply a negative answer to your question: take $a(n) = 1$ if $n\in \{b_m\colon m\in\Bbb N\}$ and $a(n)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: My idea for constructing such a sequence $\{b_m\}$ (perhaps someone can reality-check it and flesh it out?): let $A_{c,k}$ be the set of all $\lambda\in(1+\frac1k,2)$ such that $c\in S_\lambda$. If $c$ is large then the measure of $A_{c,k}$ is small. Given $b_1,\dots,b_{j-1}$, if we choose candidates for $b_j$ at random from an interval of huge integers, then the expected measure of $$A_{b_j,j} \cap \bigg( \bigcup_{i<j} A_{b_i,j} \bigg)$$ should be small. Then some zero-one law should imply that with probability $1$, any given $\lambda$ is in only finitely many of the $A_{b_j,\infty}$...?

Comment: @GregMartin: Nice approach. I think I made it work the way you intended. The problem seems to me to be that we only get a sequence $(b_j) $ such that for **almost all** $\lambda $, we have what you want. I doubt that we can get a true "for all", since we are arguing using the Lebesgue measure on $(1,2) $, so that we "don't see" a null-set.

Comment: You're probably right. So are you saying it doesn't work at all, or that you found a variant that does?

Comment: @GregMartin: What I meant is that I made your approach work, so that I could show the "for almost all $\lambda $" statement. I do not know how/if one can obtain the "for all $\lambda $" statement (from this or otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

The claim seems to be true if and only if the limit is independent of the choice of $\lambda$.

**Lemma 1:** Let $(m_n)$ be a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers. There is a subsequence of $(m_n)$ that is also a subsequence of $\left\lfloor \lambda^n \right\rfloor$, for some $\lambda \in (1,2)$.

*Proof:* Note that $\left\lfloor \lambda^{s} \right\rfloor = m$ if and only if $$\lambda \in \left[ \exp\left(\frac{\log(m)}{s} \right),\exp\left(\frac{\log(m+1)}{s} \right) \right)=\left[ m^{1/s},(m+1)^{1/s} \right).$$ Note that the interval can be made arbitrarily thin by increasing $s$, since its length is
$$(m+1)^{1/s}-m^{1/s} \leq 2^{1/s}-1.$$
By increasing $m$, the starting point of the interval can be chosen such that it's at least any $a \geq 1$. Combining these two steps, the interval of admissible $\lambda$'s can be fitted in any compact interval $[a,b]$ with $1 < a < b < 2$.

Let
$$A_i = \left[ m_{t_i}^{1/s_i},(m_{t_i}+1)^{1/s_i} \right).$$
We show that the sequences $t_i$ and $s_i$ can be chosen so that $m_{t_i}$ equals the sequence $\left\lfloor \lambda^{s_i} \right\rfloor$ for some $\lambda \in (1,2)$. Choose $s_1$ and $m_{t_1}$ so that $A_1 \subset (1,2)$. Let $C_1$ be a compact interval in $A_1$. Choose $s_2$ and $m_2$ so that $A_2 \subset C_1$. Then choose a compact interval $C_2 \subset A_2$ and choose $s_3$ and $m_{t_3}$ similarly. Repeat these steps to obtain $A_k$ and $C_k$ for any $k$. Now
$$\bigcap \limits_{k} A_k \supset \bigcap \limits_{k} C_k = C,$$
which is [nonempty as an intersection of decreasing sequence of compact sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem). Now $\lambda \in C$ is such that 
$$\lambda \in \left[ m_{t_i}^{1/s_i},(m_{t_i}+1)^{1/s_i} \right),$$
or equivalently $\left\lfloor \lambda^{s_i} \right\rfloor = m_{t_i}$ for all $i$. Hence, $m_{t_i}$ is a subsequence of  $\left\lfloor \lambda^i \right\rfloor$.

**Theorem 1:** Assume that a sequence $a_n$ satisfies the hypothesis of the above question and that the limit does not depend on the choice of $\lambda$, then the sequence $a_n$ converges.

*Proof:* Let $a_{m_n}$ be any subsequence of $a_n$. Since $m_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers, by Lemma 1, there is a subsequence of $m_n$, denoted $m_{k_n}$, which is also a subsequence of $\left\lfloor \lambda^n \right\rfloor$, for some $\lambda \in (1,2)$. Since $a_{\left\lfloor \lambda^n \right\rfloor}$ converges, $a_{m_{k_n}}$ converges as its subsequence. Since a convergent subsequence can be extracted along an arbitrary subsequence of $a_n$, [the entire sequence converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-then).