# Bounded sequence of real numbers $x_n$ converges to $x$ if and only if every subsequence of $x_n$ has a subsequence converging to $x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

How would I prove this statement? 
[Every subsequence of $x_n$ has a further subsequence which converges to $x$.Then the sequence $x_n$ converges to $x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-then)
the post here explains one way, but how would I prove the other direction?

Comment: The other direction is trivial: if $x_n \to x$, then every subsequence of $x_n$ converges to $x$, hence every subsequence has a subsequence (namely itself) which converges to $x$.