# If all proper subsequences converge to same limit then the sequence converges.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\{X_n\}_n$  be a bounded sequence. Its convergent proper subsequences converge to the same limit $\ell$.
I want to prove that $\{X_n\}_n$ converges to $\ell$.

Notice that proper subsequences are all the sequences except for the sequence itself.
Is it enough to say that $\{X_{2n}\}$ and $\{X_{2n+1}\}$ are convergent to $l$ then $\{X_n\}$ is convergent to $\ell$?

Comment: Actually one does not assume that $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n+1})$ converge to $\ell$ since the hypothesis concerns only the **convergent** subsequences, not every subsequence.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-then/2515254#2515254

Answer (score 7):

**Proof by contradiction**

Suppose that $\{X_n\}$ does not converge to $\ell$. Then, there is $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that $$\forall N\in\mathbb N,\exists n=n(N) : n>N~~~and ~~~ |X_n -\ell|>\varepsilon_0 $$

For $N_1=1$ there exists $n_1$ such that
$$n_1>N_1 ~~~and ~~~ |X_{n_1} -\ell|>\varepsilon_0 $$
Taking successively $N_{k+1}> \max\{N_k, n_k,k+1\}$ there exists $n_{k+1}>N_{k+1}$ such that,

$$ |X_{ n_{k+1}} -\ell|>\varepsilon_0 $$

It is easy to see that, $\{X_{ n_k}\}_k$ is a subsequence of $\{X_{ n}\}_n$
since
$$ n_k< n_{k+1} \quad i.e ~~\text{the map }~~k\mapsto n_k~~~\text{Is one-to-one}$$

However, $$\forall k,~~ |X_{ n_{k}} -\ell|>\varepsilon_0  \qquad  \text{and}~~~\{X_{ n_{k}} \}~~~\text{is bounded} $$

> Therefore By **Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem's** there exists $\{X_{ n_{k_p} }\}_p$ subsequence of $\{X_{ n_{k} }\}_k$ which converges to some limit $\ell_1 $
> but $\{X_{ n_{k_p} }\}_p\to \ell_1$ is also a converging subsequence of $\{X_n\}_n$

**By assumption, $\ell=\ell_1$** that is together with the fact $\{X_{ n_{k_p} }\}_p$ is a subsequence of $\{X_{ n_{k} }\}_k$ we have

$$0=\lim_{p\to\infty } |X_{ n_{k_p} }-\ell|>\varepsilon_0>0~~~\text{which is a CONTRADICTION}$$

> **Note that**
> $$\forall p,~~|X_{ n_{k_p} }-\ell|>\varepsilon_0$$
> Since
> $$\forall k,~~|X_{ n_{k}} -\ell|>\varepsilon_0$$

Comment: Why can one assume that ℓ=ℓ1? Doesn't that lead to loss of generality?

Comment: I did not assume. read the question again. $\ell$ is unique with a specific property which is fulfilled by $\ell_1$