# convergent subsequence of bounded divergent sequence, and limit of $\sup$ and $\inf$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

I happened accross this excercise:

> Let $a_n$ be a bounded, divergent sequence. Proove that there are at least two subsequences converging to different limits.

As a first strategy I thought of doing this:

Let $b_n \rightarrow L$ be a convergent subsequence (B-W theorem). Choose $\epsilon$ such that $\forall N, \exists n>N$ so that $|a_n - L|>\epsilon$. Using [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2451508/if-all-proper-subsequences-converge-to-same-limit-then-the-sequence-converges), build a subsequence as follows:

$n_1 = \min(n>1 / |a_n-L|>\epsilon)$

$n_k = \min(n>n_{k-1}/ |a_n-L|>\epsilon)$

The set $a_{n_k}, k>=1$ is a subsequence of $a_n$, therefore bounded, therefore contains a convergent subsequence, which cannot converge to $L$ (**first question**: is this ok?)

Moreover I wondered if $sup$ and $inf$ of the sequence can be used, and what are their properties. Is the following reasoning correct?

Let $S_k = {a_n, n>=k}$, since all $S_k$ are bounded sequences, $sup(S_k)$ exists. Furthermore, since $S_1\supset S_2 \supset S_3 ...$ then $\sup(S_1)\geq \sup(S_2)\geq \sup(S_3) ...$. Therefore, the sequence $\sup(S_1), \sup(S_2)...$ is monotone and bounded (therefore convergent).

**Third question**, is it true that $\displaystyle L = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\inf(S_n) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup(S_n) \Leftrightarrow a_n\rightarrow L$?

Thanks

Comment: 3RD Q: Yes. If $A=(a_n)_n$ is a bounded real sequence then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{m\ge n}a_m$is the largest limit of a subsequence of $A$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{m\ge n}a_m$  is the smallest limit of a subsequence of $A.$ And  $A$ is convergent iff all subsequences of $A$ converge to the same limit