# A subsequence of the worst-case subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

I know the useful fact for sequences stated in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-the).

However, suppose I have an arbitrary sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and I want to prove that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_{n} \geq c$ from some $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

We know by definition of $\liminf$ that there exists a subsequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such that: $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{a_{n}}$$
My question is: to complete the proof does it suffice to show that there exists a further subsequence $\{b_{n}\}\subseteq \{a_{n}\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{b_{n}} \geq c$?

**Background:** The only reason I feel it is possible is that the first subsequence $\{a_{n}\}$
 is, in some sense, the "worst case" subsequence. This makes me feel it might be possible to show that if this worst case subsequence has a subsequence converging to $x \geq c$, then the same might be true for **every** subsequence of the original sequence. I could then apply the result in the link I posted above.

Comment: Yes, although you do need to know that the $\lim \inf$ is defined for the initial sequence $\{x_n\}$, i.e., that it is bounded below. Your phrasing asks about an *arbitrary* real-valued sequence, which is too general a criterion to satisfy.

Comment: If the sequence $S=(x_{a_n})_n$ converges to $c$ then every sub-sequence of $S$ will also converge to $c$..... Note  that $c=\lim \inf x_n\in \Bbb R$  iff $c$  is the least limit-value of a convergent sub-sequence of $(x_n)_n .$