# What is an example of a sequence of random variables $|Y_n|\leq 1$ converging in probability to $0$ but the variance is either constant or blows up?

Tags: probability

I am trying to come up with an example of a sequence of random variables $|Y_n|\leq 1$ converging in probability to $0$, but where the variance $Var(Y_n)$ does not converge to $0$ in limit. Is there a way I can use a transformation of a variable $Y_n ~ Bern\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$?

Comment: Doesn't such example contradict dominated convergence theorem for convergence in probability?

Comment: Which part does it contradict? thanks!

Comment: I mean the variance should go to zero by DCT... So you cannot find an example

Comment: How could I prove the variance goes to zero by the DCT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Such example cannot exist.**

Why? Well, let
$$a_n:=\operatorname{Var}(Y_n) $$
Take a subsequence $a_{n_k} $, note that $Y_{n_k} $ still converges in probability to zero. It has a further subsequence $Y_{n_{k_j}}$ converging almost surely to zero. Since $|Y_{n_{k_j}}|\leq 1$ a.s., we have $|Y_{n_{k_j}}^2|\leq 1$ a.s.. Hence by DCT
$$a_{n_{k_j}} = \mathbb E(Y_{n_{k_j}}^2)-\mathbb E(Y_{n_{k_j}}) ^2\to 0$$
as $j\to\infty$.

So every subsequence of $a_n$ has a further subsequence converging to zero. So the sequence $a_n$ converges to zero by [this fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397978).

Answer (score 1):

*Reversed* binomial distribution described bellow worked.

**EDIT**: The $Y_m$ I constructed may not satisfy the condition "converging in probability to $0$". It may be modified but I couldn't find precisely what "converging in probability to $0$" means.

**EDIT**: I found the definition of "converging in probability to $0$" in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability) and that my example does not work.

(My trial was:
Let $P( X_m=j/m ) = (1/4)^m * (2m)!/(m-j)!(m+j)!$ for $-m\leq j\leq m$,
for $-m< j<0$, $P( Y_m=-1-j/m ) = P( X_m=j/m )$
for $0<j< m, P( Y_m=1-j/m ) = P( X_m=j/m )$
for $j=-m,0,m, P( Y_m=j/m ) = P( X_m=j/m ) $)