# Strange characterlization of convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let {${a_n}$} be sequence of real number.

I understand the the fact that

(ⅰ) {${a_n}$} converges to $a$ when $n→∞$

(ⅱ)For arbitrary strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers ${n(i)}$, there exists strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers ${n(j)}$, such that {${a_n(i(j))}$} converges to $a$ when $j→∞$.

My question : What kind of benefit from characterizing congvergence like (ⅱ)?
Also, I have never seen this characterization in any reference. If you could find any refference about this, I would be grateful if you could tell me.

Comment: This is usually stated as an exercise I guess.. I remember using this to prove that every injective continuous function $f : E\to \mathbb R$ from a compact set in $E\subset \mathbb R$ has a continuous inverse.

Comment: Some reference in MSE: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-the)