# Does $H^1(a, b)$ convergence imply pointwise convergence a.e. for the weak derivative?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $(q_n)_n$ be a sequence in $H^1(a, b)$ that converges to some $q\in H^1(a, b)$. I would like to know if it is true that $q_n'(t)\to q'(t)$ for a.e. $t\in (a, b)$.

I believe it is and here is what I tried to do. Consider a subsequence $(q_{n_k})_k$ of $(q_n)_n$. Then, we also have $q_{n_k}\to q$ in $H^1(a, b)$, so, in particular, $q_{n_k}'\to q'$ in $L^2(a, b)$, which says that there is some subsequence $(q_{n_{k_l}})_l$ of $(q_{n_k})_k$ that converges pointwise for a.e. $t\in (a, b)$ to $q'(t)$. Therefore, by the subsequence principle I believe that we may conclude that $q_n'(t)\to q'(t)$ for a.e. $t\in (a, b)$. Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by subsequence principle?

Comment: @Kandinskij https://math.stackexchange.com/q/397978/589373 it is this Lemma. Isn't my argument precisely an application of this or am I too tired and I messed it up somehow?

Comment: @MW why do you need the topology to be metrizable? See the link above, this works in any topological space if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @JustAnAmateur You are correct subsequence principle is fine for general topology, unless we are both missing something, apologies for jumping the gun on that explanation.  The issue is that pointwise ae convergence doesn’t come from a topology at all.

Comment: @MW thank you very much! I wasn't aware of this, but I looked it up now and you are correct. Now I see why my argument doesn't work.

Comment: @JustAnAmateur I would add that if there were such a topology, then your argument would already show that $L^2$ convergence implies ae convergence, which is of course false since you can take $f_n =\chi_{I_n}$ where $I_n$ enumerates the diadic intervals in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Let $[c,d]\subseteq [a,b]$ and let $F_{[c,d]}:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined as follows:

1. Constantly zero for $x\leq c$ and for $x\geq d$
2. It grows linearly with slope $1$ in the first half $[c,d]$. It decreases linearly with slope $-1$ in the second half of $[c,d]$

Now I define the family of subintervals $(I_{ij})_{i\in \mathbb{N},j\leq i}$ to be the subinterval of $[a,b]$ obtained as follows

- Partition $[a,b]$ into $i$ subintervals of measure $(b-a)/i$
- $I_{ij}$ is the $j$-th interval in this partition.

Now I define the following sequence of intervals
$$I_{11},I_{21},I_{22},I_{31},I_{32},I_{33},I_{41},...$$
and I indicate with $J_n$ the $n$-th interval of this sequence.
Can you see that $q_n:=F_{J_n}$ is a counterexample?

Comment: I tend to believe that your counterexample works, but could you please fill in some details so that it is more clear why this is a counterexample?

Comment: Is it clear to you that this sequence converges to $0$ in $H^1$ ?

Comment: I don't know how to easily see that rigorously, but I feel like it does converge to $0$ in $H^1$, yes.

Comment: Clearly the maximum of $F_{[c,d]}$ is reached in the middle point of $[c,d]$ and it's $(d-c)/2=\mathcal{L}[c,d]/2$ so clearly $|F_{J_n}|\leq \frac{\mathcal{L}(J_n)}{2}\chi_{J_n}$. This implies that $||F_{J_n}||_{L^2}\leq ||\frac{\mathcal{L}(J_n)}{2}\chi_{J_n}||_{L^2}=\frac{\mathcal{L}(J_n)^2}{2}$. Clearly as $n\to \infty$ the RHS converges to 0. So $F_{J_n}$ converges to $0$ in $L^2$. A similar reasoning applies to the weak derivative of $F_{J_n}$ (which is equal to the classical derivative almost everywhere since $F_{J_n}$ is a continous piecewise $C^1$ function). Is it now more clear?

Comment: yes, it is, I can see it now, thanks.

Comment: And can you see that derivatives $F_{J_n}'$ don't converge almost everywhere to $0$?

Comment: yes, I can, thank you for your help!