# Convergence in measure and convergence of integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, self-learning

Let $g_n:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are measurable, suppose $g_n \rightarrow 0$ in measure, and $\int g_n^2 dm\leq 1$ for all $n$. Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $\int f^2 dm< \infty$, prove that $\int fg_n dm \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Here $m$ stands for the Lebesgue measure.

My attempt is: since $g_n \rightarrow 0$ in measure, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N>0$ s.t. $m(\{|g_n|>\epsilon\})<\epsilon$. So by Cauchy -Schwarz inequality,
$$\left|\int fg_n\right| \leq \int_{\{|g_n|>\epsilon\}}|fg_n|+\int_{\{|g_n|\leq\epsilon\}}|fg_n|\leq \left(\int_{\{|g_n|>\epsilon\}}f^2 \right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{\{|g_n|>\epsilon\}}g_n^2 \right)^{1/2} + \epsilon\int_{\{|g_n|\leq\epsilon\}}|f|$$

Here I got stuck, the $(\int_{\{|g_n|>\epsilon\}}g_n^2)^{1/2} \leq 1$ is obvious, but I don't know how to bound $(\int_{\{|g_n|>\epsilon\}}f^2 )^{1/2}$ and $\int_{\{|g_n|\leq\epsilon\}}|f|$.

Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I might add a further approach to the ones presented by @MW based on an application of [uniform integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability) and [Vitali's convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem). In a $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$, one of the characterisations of uniform integrability for $L^1$ functions is the following: a subset of functions $\mathscr{F}\subseteq L^1$ is said to be uniformly integrable if we have $\sup_{v \in \mathscr{F}}\int |v|<\infty$ and for any decreasing sequence of measurable sets $A_k\downarrow \emptyset$ we have $\lim_k \sup_{v \in \mathscr{F}}\int_{A_k} |v|=0$. A reference for this is in [Schilling's book](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/universitypress/subjects/statistics-probability/probability-theory-and-stochastic-processes/measures-integrals-and-martingales-2nd-edition?format=PB&isbn=9781316620243). Now if we consider $(fg_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and the fact that the Lebesgue measure is $\sigma$-finite we have that by CS inequality and the assumption $\|g_n\|_{L^2}\leq 1$
$$\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\int |fg_n|\leq \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\|f\|_{L^2}\|g_n\|_{L^2}\leq \|f\|_{L^2}<\infty$$
while we also have by dominated convergence (since $f \in L^2$):
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\int_{A_k}|fg_n|\leq \lim_{k\to \infty}\|\mathbf{1}_{A_k}f\|_{L^2}=0$$
therefore our sequence is uniformly integrable. We also have that $fg_n\to 0$ in measure, this can be seen by $\mu(|fg_n|>\varepsilon)\leq \mu(|f|>k)+\mu(|g_n|>\varepsilon/k),\forall n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ then sending $n$ to infinity, and then $k$ to infinity. Therefore we can apply Vitali's convergence theorem and obtain $\int |fg_n|\to 0$.

Comment: When you write "decreasing" sequence of sets $A_k\downarrow \emptyset$ in the definition of uniform integrability, I presume this means they are nested?  If so, that seems different than the definition of "uniformly absolutely continuous integrals" at the Wikipedia link, which is used in their formulation of Vitali's theorem.  Also, their formulation of the theorem(condition 3) requires finite measure sets $X_\epsilon$ away from which the integrals are uniformly bounded by $\epsilon$.  Not doubting the proof but is there an easy way to see how this setup fits the Wikipedia formulation?

Comment: Hmm I think I see how to resolve my previous comment - use a rapidly converging subsequence of sets to extend from the nested case to the arbitrary decreasing measure case, and as to the second point, if $\cdots S_i\subseteq S_{i+1}\cdots$ is an exhaustion of $X$ by finite measure sets, then your condition on the limsup, with $A_k=X\backslash S_k$, gives condition 3 at wiki link.  I'll leave these comments in case anyone else is confused as I was.

Comment: Hello @MW: yes, decreasing means $A_k\supseteq A_{k+1}\supseteq ...$. Do have a look at the reference: the author presents a big theorem (Th. 22.9) in which up to ten (!) definitions of uniform integrability are shown to be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Throughout, we assume with no loss of generality that $f$ and $g_n$ are nonnegative, since if we prove the theorem replacing $f$ and $g_n$ with $|f|$ and $|g_n|$ then the result follows.

[Update: the original proof used machinery that you might not have been exposed to and that on reflection is not really necessary, so I have included an alternative argument using only dominated convergence.]

---

#### Proof via dominated convergence

Let $\delta>0$. Now, for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$ and $\eta>0$ we have (by dominated convergence)
$$\int_{\{f>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}\cup \{f<\eta\}}f^2\leq \delta^2\text{.}$$
To see that this follows from dominated convergence, just observe that the sequence of functions
$f^2\chi_{\{f>m\}\cup \{f<\frac{1}{m}\}}$ converges pointwise to $0$ and is dominated by $f^2$.

Therefore for all $g_n$ we have
$$\int_{\{f>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}\cup \{f<\eta\}}fg_n
\leq 
\left(\int_{\{f>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}\cup \{f<\eta\}}f^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \left(\int_{\{f>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}\cup \{f<\eta\}}g_n^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\leq
\delta\text{.}\tag{1}$$

Fixing any such $\eta$ and $\epsilon$, we also have your inequalities, but with the integrands restricted further to $\{\eta\leq f\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}$, and also we will actually choose $N$ large enough so that for $n>N$ we have $m(\{|g_n|>\epsilon^3\})<\epsilon^3$, so that for large enough $n$ we get

\begin{align*}
\int_{\{\eta\leq f\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}} fg_n & \leq \left(\int_{\{g_n>\epsilon^3\}\cap \{\eta\leq f\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}}f^2 \right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{\{g_n>\epsilon^3\}\cap\{\eta\leq f\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}}g_n^2 \right)^{1/2} \\ &+ \epsilon^3\int_{\{g_n\leq\epsilon^3\}\cap\{\eta\leq f\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}}f\tag{2}\\
& \leq \epsilon^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 1 + \frac{\epsilon^3}{\eta}\int_{\{g_n\leq\epsilon^3\}\cap\{\eta\leq f\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}}f^2
\end{align*}

Then letting $\epsilon\to 0$ and combining (1) and (2) gives
$$\overline{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\int fg_n \leq \overline{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\int_{\{f>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}\cup \{f<\eta\}}fg_n + \overline{\lim_{n\to\infty}}\int_{\{\eta\leq f\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\}} fg_n\leq \delta\text{,}
$$
and since $\delta$ was arbitrary this completes the proof.

---

#### Proof via Banach–Alaoglu theorem

From the [subsequence principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-the) it is enough to show that every subsequence of $\int fg_n$ has a further subsequence which converges to $0$.  But since every subsequence of $g_n$ satisfies the assumptions of the original sequence, this reduces our task to finding a single subsequence of the original sequence $\int fg_n$ that converges.

Now, by the [weak-* compactness of the ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem) in $L^2(\mathbb R)$, there is a subsequence of $g_n$ (which we immediately rename as $g_n$ itself) that converges weak-* to some $g\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, i.e., $\int h g_n\to \int hg$ for each $h\in L^2(\mathbb R)$.  (Here we are also using the characterization of the dual of $L^2$ via the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem))

It therefore suffices to show that $g=0$ almost everywhere, as we may take $h=f$.  Equivalently, we will show that $\int_A g=0$ for all $A$ with $m(A)<\infty$.  To do this, we fix such $A$ and then simply repeat your calculation replacing $f$ with $\chi_A$:

\begin{align*}
\int \chi_A g_n & \leq \int_{\{g_n>\epsilon\}}\chi_A g_n+\int_{\{g_n\leq\epsilon\}}\chi_A g_n\\
&\leq \left(\int_{\{g_n>\epsilon\}}\chi_A^2 \right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{\{g_n>\epsilon\}}g_n^2 \right)^{1/2} + \epsilon\int_{\{g_n\leq\epsilon\}}\chi_A\\
& \leq \epsilon^{1/2}\cdot 1 + \epsilon m(A)
\end{align*}
and so letting $\epsilon\to 0$ establishes that $\int g_n\chi_A\to 0$, whereby from weak convergence of $g_n$ we have $\int_A g = \int g\chi_A=0$, as desired.

Comment: It looks like this problem is more complicated than I thought. I was expecting a simpler solution lol.

Comment: @AlexHe I thought of a way to avoid the business about weak compactness of the ball in $L^2$, and all the subsequence business, in case you haven't encountered that stuff.  I posted an updated answer using just dominated convergence.

Comment: @MW I was reading your update and I noticed I don't get the second inequality in $(2)$: could you explain quickly?

Comment: @Snoop so we've got two terms with two factors each, and they more or less line up directly, the left term we are applying $f\leq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and using bound on $m(\{g_n>\epsilon^3\})$ (for first factor) and the $L^2$ bound on $g_n$, (for second factor), second term we are using $f\geq \eta$ so we may multiply integrand by $\frac{f}{\eta}\geq 1$.