About the converse of below theorem
My book states that

if a sequence $a_n$
converges to $l$, then every subsequence also converges to $l$.

Now it states at the end that its converse is not true. but as we know that if every subsequence converges to same limit $l$ then $a_n$ also converges to $l$. Kindly tell me if am wrong in understanding the converse or the author has made any mistake.
There should be iff condition in the above theorem.

Pretty sure they mean that if a specific subsequence tends to $l$, you can't conclude that $a_n$ tends to $l$ as well. (nor that it converges at all)

@Mark pointed out one possible correct interpretation. Note that another similar result which is implied by this but whose converse is not true is "If $a_n\to l$ then every convergent subsequence of $a_n\to l$". The converse of this is not true since a divergent sequence may have no convergent subsequence.

You might also be interested in the "subsequence principle" explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397978/every-subsequence-of-x-n-has-a-further-subsequence-which-converges-to-x-the
